# How to prove that function $f$ must be injective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, inverse

I'm strugling a lot with the following proof.

let $f: X \rightarrow Y $

proof that $$\forall A \in P(X): A=f^{-1}(f(A)) \iff f \text{ is injective}$$

So I know how to proof that if f is injective then ... . But somehow I can't find a way to prove that f must be injective. If someone knows the answer please consider sharing the answer with me.

**what I know**

- $A \in P(X)$ means that $A \subset X$
- $f^{-1}(y) = \{x \in X | f(x) = y\} $ which implies that $x\in f^{-1}(y) \implies f(x)=y$
- $\forall x_1,x_2 \in X: f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$   (definition injective)

**Why I struggle**

So I know in order to prove that something is injective you  first start with you know  which is: $$\text{let }\forall A \in P(X): A=f^{-1}(f(A))$$
and then you say:
$$\text{suppose }f(x_1) = f(x_2)$$
So know I have to find something in my given such that $x_1 = x_2$. But I can't seem to find a way. I tried something like this:
$$A=f^{-1}(f(A))$$
$$f(A)=f(A)$$
$$A=A$$
But as you can see this doesn't prove anything, so if you can help me, please do :).

Comment: What's f? I think initial information is missing.

Comment: ow srry I forgot It is f: X -> Y, I will adjust it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick here is that once you've assumed the left-hand side - $\forall A \in P(X): A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ - you can pick the subset $A$ that you apply it to. Here, take $A$ to be the singleton $\{x_1\}$.

Since $f(x_2) = f(x_1)$, $x_2$ must be an element of $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\}))$. (Check this for yourself) Can you conclude from there?

Comment: thank you in advance for your reply, I get that $x_2$ is an element of $f^{-1}\left(f\left(\left\{x_{1}\right\}\right)\right)$ But how can you say that $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: Sorry that this may be a dumb question to ask, but I just don't understand how you can proof this

Comment: @TheCreator You still need to use the assumption. What do you know about $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\}))$, because you know it's true for all sets of that form?

Comment: I know that $f^{-1}\left(f\left(\left\{x_{1}\right\}\right)\right) = x_1$, ow I see so that implies that $x_1 = x_2$. Woa thank you very much

Comment: @TheCreator Just in case, note that the set is equal to $\{x_1\}$, the singleton set, and not $x_1$, the element.

Comment: I see, but doesn't that mean that $\{x_1\} = x_2$ so that doesn't prove injectivity or am I wrong?

Comment: @TheCreator $x_2$ is an element of $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\})) = \{x_1\}$, not equal to it.

Comment: Ok, so what your trying to say is, because $x_2 \in \{x_1 \}$we can conclude that $x_1 = x_2$ am I right?